# Facing Error while accessing SharePoint site list, The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365-developer, 401, c-sharp

I am getting following error

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

While I'm trying to read a website hosted in SharePoint.
I have tried following code to access my SharePoint site via my C#.

```
String Id="xyz.onmicrosoft.com";
String pass="Password";
SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char ch in pass)
                password.AppendChar(ch);
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/parts/");
            using (var context = new ClientContext(uri)) 
            {
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Id,password);
                Web web=context.Web;
                context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                System.Console.WriteLine("Web Title");
                System.Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
            }
```

I didn't get to know whats wrong with this code. I have tried some forum solutions as well but they didn't worth to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```